# systemctl shows Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitte

Tags: centos, d-bus, systemctl

os：CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core),physical machine not docker ,not virtual machine

I upgrade clickhouse first with `yum localinstall ./clickhouse-*.rpm`, and then I regreted, I downgrade clickhouse with `yum downgrade clickhouse-xx-xx.rpm`,and then I find `systemctl status clickhouse-server` throw

```bash
# systemctl status clickhouse-server
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

and also

```bash
[root@cu75 ~]# systemctl
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
[root@cu75 ~]# systemctl start dbus
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
[root@cu75 ~]#
```

but dbus is running

```bash
[root@cu75 ~]# ps -ef | grep dbus
dbus       1646      1  0  2021 ?        00:48:47 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root      44000      1  0 15:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/abrt-dbus -t133
root      44363 429726  0 15:32 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dbus
gdm      240198      1  0  2021 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
gdm      240199      1  0  2021 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
gdm      240224 240219  0  2021 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
luhongw+ 436050      1  0 14:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
root     436172      1  0 14:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
[root@cu75 ~]#
```

I checked for all similar questions in this website ,but most of them are docker images, is there any solution to resolve it?